# Plot global projected raster in R

Tags: r, plot, r-raster, proj

I'm trying to plot a global (lon:-180- 180; lat -90- 90) raster in Equal Earth projection (doesn't matter - could be Winkel Tripel or Robinson) but the boundaries duplicate on both sides (see figure). How can I avoid this?

[This SO question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGCwS.png) and [this thread](http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/Difficulties-with-Eckert-IV-Mollweide-projection-of-RasterLayer-with-global-extent-td7580864.html) give an answer that only works for plotting in Mollweide, but no other projection.

Here's a reproducible example.

```
library(maptools)
library(raster)
data("wrld_simpl")
r <- raster(ncol=180, nrow=90) 
r <- rasterize(wrld_simpl, r, field="UN") 
world_ext = projectExtent(wrld_simpl, crs = '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs ')
r <- crop(x = r, y = world_ext, snap= 'in')
r <- projectRaster(r, crs = crs("+proj=wintri"), over = T)
plot(r)
```

Many thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `mask=TRUE` argument in `terra::project` for this

```
library(maptools)
library(terra)
data("wrld_simpl")
w <- vect(wrld_simpl)
r <- rast(ncol=180, nrow=90) 
r <- rasterize(w, r, field="UN") 
x <- project(r, "+proj=wintri", mask=TRUE)
```